# how can i get to the propertys of a folder inside of a folder

Tags: minecraft, 17.04

i downloaded a minecraft mod creator called MCreator, i had to create a zip folder with it so i did. it kept saying that its not  executable, it wasn't the zip folder but it was a folder inside of the folder. i went to the folder to go to the properties but it didn't show properties. i don't know how to change it with the console. the file name is MCreator.jar. i have tried to extract the folder and make it executable but when i put it back in it turns back to non-executable. is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

To run a `.jar` file you just type `sudo chmod +x [NameOfFile]` and then `java -jar [NameOfFile]`